Evaluating a one-sided limit that goes to negative infinity, where the denominator goes to $0$
I attached my handwriting explaining the issue, hope that's okay.
Basically, I can "intuitively" find the limit and explain it on paper.
However, I'm not sure if this "approach" is "formal" and correct enough (in the context of a formal calculus discussion, as opposed to an intuitive discussion).
As you can see, in the second ("working") approach, I sort of use the "1+" and "0-" symbols in the denominator, to explain why this goes to negative infinity.
While I'm aware that every calculus class may have its own standards regarding proofs, I assume that with relation to this basic material, there exists a standard in mathematics which guides how proofs like this can and cannot look. So I'm looking for this sort of guidance.
Therefore, I believe this question is objective enough to be posted on this site.
Please give an example of how you would compute this limit correctly.


You could make this approach more formal, but the level of formality isn't something that can be answered objectively.  It depends on the situation.

@MichaelBurr Can you give me an example of how you would evaluate this limit formally (in a way which would be expected in a standard calculus 1 class), other than going from the epsilon delta definition? I just think I'm missing something, couldn't find a way.

I guess what really bothers you is to write $1^+$ inside the solution. Therefore, I will suggest a way to avoid doing so. Your claim that $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{1}{1-3^\frac{x}{x+2}} = \frac{1}{1-\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0^+}}3^\frac{x}{x+2}}$$ holds because (1) the limit of a quotient is the quotient of the limits: $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{1}{1-3^\frac{x}{x+2}} = \frac{\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0^+}1}}{\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0^+}(1-3^\frac{x}{x+2}})}$$
and (2) the limit of a difference is the difference of the limits: $$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0^+}(1-3^\frac{x}{x+2})} = \lim_{x \to 0^+}1-\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0^+}3^\frac{x}{x+2}}$$
Since $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}1=1$$ you get the first equality I wrote. To conclude, it can be helpful to observe that exponential functions, quotients of continuous functions (if the function in the denominator is not $0$) and composition of continuous functions are continuous , so $$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0^+}3^\frac{x}{x+2}}=3^{\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x}{x+2}}}$$
Note that the limit is $0^+$. Probably the best thing to do now is pointing out that $3^b>1$ if $b>0$, so the denominator is $0^-$ and the starting limit is $-\infty$. Maybe it is better if you do not write explicitly these last steps but evaluate the limit globally at the end.
